# Redux-router + React. How to trigger pre-loading data(initial) for component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Good night everyone! I can't find any info about loading data for view without using componentDidMount/componentWillMount in component. May be exist any elegant method for loading data exactly when i redirecting to url, not when component rendering?

Now i configurate router:

```
<ReduxRouter>
      <Route component={App}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path='path' component={pathComponent} />
      </Route>
    </ReduxRouter>
```

And already in component write:

```
export default class pathComponent extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.getData()
    }
}
```

But this is not so good to keep some logic in dumb component...

Comment: You are looking for [Container Components](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.y6a6zau0k)

Comment: You can use the `onEnter` hook with react router, and fetch the data there

Comment: Can you tell me where that method should live :-)? @Dylan

Comment: Does this fetched data get written to your redux store?

Comment: yes, of course @Dylan

Comment: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback